# i wanna return correctly children's object. how can i?

Tags: javascript

```
function Ha8(arr, id) {
  let result = [];
  for(let i = 0;  i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i].children)) {
     // if it is a array, it going to be run recursive
      result.push(arr[i].children)
    const col = Ha8(result[i], id);
      if(col === id)  {
        // find it in array in array 
        return result
        // then return the id object, 
      } else {
        continue; // still can't find.. go ahead! 
      }  
    } else if (arr[i]['id']===id) {
      return arr[i] // will return valid id object 
  }
  return null // if its none , return null, or parameter id is undefined. 
 }
}
```

I m write Intended direction. but its not work..
how can i fix ? give me some tip please.

```
let input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'johnny',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'ingi',
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'johnson',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'steve',
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'lisa',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 11,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '13',
  },
];

output = Ha8(input, 5);
console.log(output); // --> { id: 5, name: 'steve', children: [{ id: 6, name: 'lisa' }] }

output = Ha8(input, 99);
console.log(output); // --> null
```

I wanna return like that, but only return 'null' ..
need to check children's id and return children's object by using recursive.
so i write like that. but i have no idea..
how to return correctly children id's element?

Comment: I believe `if(col === id)` should be `if(col && col.id === id)`.  You also have to swap the condition. You have to check the ID of the object first before you traverse its children (if it has any).

Comment: Ahhhhhhh thanks to your tip!

Comment: hmm still not work.. i swaped 'col.id'. but.. why col === col && col.id ?  i dont understand.. could you more explain to me ?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I said you should check the object ID first before traversing its children (swap the checks): `if (arr[i]['id']===id) { ... } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i].children)) { ... }`.

Comment: @Felix Kling ohh thanks , finally i m fixed but still have a different error xd hahaha omg..  
i will upload other issue... thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an answer using a totally different approach, and using the magic of the `JSON.stringify()` method, more specifically the `replacer` optional parameter, which allows the use of a callback function that can be used as a filter.

As you can see, it simplifies a lot the final code. It could also be modified to introduce not only an id, but also any key or value, as I did in my final approach.

**EDIT:** Following your suggestion, as you prefer your function to be recursive, I recommend you to use the `Array.reduce()` method. It allows an elegant iteration through all the properties until the needs are met.

Using `null` as initial value, which is the last argument of the `reduce` method, it allows to iterate through all fields in the array in the following way:

- The first if will always be skipped on the first iteration, as the initial value is null.
- The second if will set the currentValue to the accumulator if the property id exists and is equal to the value you are trying to find
- The third if, which you could add an `Array.isArray()` to add a type validation, will check if the property `children` exists. As it is the last one, it will only work if all the other conditions aren't met. If this property exists, it will call again `Ha8Recursive` in order to start again the process.
- Finally, if neither of this works, it should return `null`. The absence of this last condition would return `undefined` if the input id doesn't exist

```js
const Ha8 = (array, inputKey, inputValue) => {
    let children = null;
    JSON.stringify(array, (key, value) => {
        if (value[inputKey] && value[inputKey] === inputValue) {
            children = value;
        }
        return value;
    });
    return children;
};

const Ha8Recursive = (array, inputKey, inputValue) => {
    return array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if (accumulator) {
            return accumulator;
        } else if (currentValue[inputKey] && currentValue[inputKey] === inputValue) {
            return currentValue;
        } else if (currentValue.children) {
            return Ha8Recursive(currentValue.children, inputKey, inputValue);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }, null)
}

const input = [{"id":1,"name":"johnny"},{"id":2,"name":"ingi","children":[{"id":3,"name":"johnson"},{"id":5,"name":"steve","children":[{"id":6,"name":"lisa"}]},{"id":11}]},{"id":"13"}];

console.log('JSON stringify function');
console.log(Ha8(input, 'id', 5));
console.log('Recursive function')
console.log(Ha8Recursive(input, 'id', 5));
```

Comment: thanks your favor. but i want to using recursion